# 12.04 splash screen freeze after upgrades

Tags: 12.04, freeze, plymouth

This is 12.04 LTS on an AMD A8-3870 APU with Radeon(tm) HD Graphics.

Had 12.04 installed for a couple of weeks.  Previously updated ~1 week ago.

Installed konqueror + available updates on 25/May apparently successfully.

On reboot, machine hangs in KDE splash screen, before login dialogue.
No response to num lock, or other keys.

Can run recovery mode command prompt & networking.

Is there a way to find what updates were applied, and roll them back ?

Is there a way to stop the gui splash screen, and display text startup logging instead ?

Comment: To disable splash screen do this at terminal: `sudo nano /etc/default/grub` then change the line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""`; save; the run `sudo update-grub`

Comment: Then post here what errors do you get. Sometimes if you press "Esc" at splash screen you will be able to see the text info.

Comment: Thankyou for that. I suspect it is freezing during X initialisation. Boot seems to proceed OK. With GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="" I briefly see a text login prompt, then it hangs. grub.cfg seems to have changed quite a bit. I used to have "nomodeset" at the end of the usual boot line, to allow a VGA monitor, but that has gone, and seems not to be necessary.

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).